# ng-click inside ng-repeat not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click, route-provider

I am using routeProvider to route to "views/userspace.html" which uses "UserspaceController"

The "views/userspace.html" recognizes this controller and makes request a $http request. This request works file and i can see values in "views/userspace.html" (inside ng-repeat). However, in the same controller i have defined `$scope.videoClick` function which does not seems to work. Any idea why?

```
   var application = angular.module("tss.application", 
    [
        "ngRoute",
        "ui.bootstrap"
    ]);

    application.config(function($routeProvider) 
    {
      $routeProvider
          .when("/", {
            templateUrl : "views/main.html",
            controller: "LoginController"
          })
          .when("/files", {
            templateUrl : "views/userspace.html",
            controller: "UserspaceController"
          });
    });
```

**userspace_controller.js**

```
  angular.module('tss.application').controller("UserspaceController",  
    function($scope, $log, $http, $uibModal)
    {       
        $http(
            {
                url     : "/dirlist",
                method  : "GET",
            }).then(function successCallback(response) 
            {
                $scope.lists = response.data;
            }, 
            function errorCallback(response) 
            {
                window.alert("Dir list could not be get");
            });     
        $scope.videoClick = function()
        {           
            $log.info('received.');
            $uibModal.open(
            {
                templateUrl: '/views/content.html',

            });
        };          
    });
```

**userspace.html**

```
   <li ng-repeat="list in lists" ng-click="videoClick(list.src)">{{list.name}}</li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Change your function to accept a parameter

```
$scope.videoClick = function(val) {
    $log.info('received.');
    $uibModal.open({
        templateUrl: '/views/content.html',

    });
};
```

Or change the function in HTML

```
<li ng-repeat="list in lists" ng-click="videoClick()">{{list.name}}</li>
```

Comment: how do i login to the app?

Comment: username - n, password - a

Comment: do you have a team viewer to login and fix?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128281/discussion-between-sajeetharan-and-nishant).

Comment: password is what?

Comment: apssword - 8665

Answer (score 0):

It's because in your;

```
$scope.videoClick = function()
    {           
        $log.info('received.');
        $uibModal.open(
        {
            templateUrl: '/views/content.html',

        });
    };
```

You have a comma which isn't needed, which makes the function throw an error because it's expecting another property.

Also if you're using the variable you pass through your HTML, you should use Sajeetharan's answer.